# Computer is incompatible to g driver setup

Tags: windows, drivers

So recently my windows got corrupted and I installed a new version of windows (Windows 7 Professional) but when I am trying to install the G-Driver that I used before it is saying that your pc is incompatible with the setup. I didn't even change any of the hardware. Why is it happening? Maybe because my previous version was Windows 7 Ultimate or something else. Please help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's "G-Driver"?

Comment: An alternative solution (but not recommended) is to search for an outdated version of the driver that is still compatible with Windows 7.

Comment: Please give details about the "G-Driver", what it is and where it's coming from, and add a screenshot of the error message. For installation, there is no difference between Windows 7 Professional and Ultimate.

Answer (score 4):

> I installed a new version of windows (Windows 7 Professional)

Windows 7 is so old that it will no longer even update. That is the issue with your driver.

In addition, Windows 7 is risky and insecure.

You need to upgrade to a supported version of Windows. Most Windows 7 computers will also run Windows 10, so upgrade to Windows 10.